NTRU: Does the ```*``` indicates something more than a simple multiplication, so for that reason omitted from ```ph``` instead of ```p*h```?
I read the literature and more specific a book describing NTRU encryption. Somewhere (among other things) it describes the "encrpyption", etc... between Alice and Bob.
The author writes:
$e\equiv pr*h+m\pmod q$
Does it have any difference if we write:
$e\equiv p*r*h+m\pmod q$
Does the * indicates something more than a simple multiplication, so for that reason omitted from ph instead of p*h??

Two comments: 1) if you're asking questions about what a book says, it might be helpful if you mention which book you're talking about, and 2) might the book be referring to pr as a single variable (with a two letter name)?

Please look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTRUEncrypt It uses the same rationale by putting . instead of *, what does it mean? Do I miss something? I also think that p and r are different variables...

Please edit with more information: link to the reference, or/and formula as a picture or best in LaTex/Mathjax like $e\equiv pr*h+m\pmod q$ which is entered as $e\equiv pr*h+m\pmod q$ (or to get in centered in a separate display as $$e\equiv pr*h+m\pmod q$$).

First off, there are several standard ways to designate a 'multiplication' operation.  If we are multiplying two values $a$ and $b$, we can write:
$$a \times b$$
$$a \cdot b$$
$$ab$$
In addition, when the designers of Fortran needed a symbol that appeared on punch cards to denote multiplication, they picked the asterisk (and most computer languages followed in that tradition), and so we have a*b as well.
However, these are all just ways of expressing 'multiplication', there is no semantic difference between them.
On the other hand, we have lots of operations that we generally denote as 'multiplication'; we can multiply two integers, or two elements of a finite field, or two matrices, to give a few examples.  Because of this variety, it is impractical to have a different multiply symbol for each type; instead we rely on context, generally assuming the reader will be able to deduce the precise type based on the types of the operands we're multiplying.
When we write $r \cdot h$ in the context of NTRU, what we mean is that both $r$ and $h$ are NTRU ring elements, and so the multiplication is an NTRU multiplication (which results in an NTRU ring element).
However, when we write $pr$ (using the third way of expressing multiplication I mentioned), what the authors most likely meant (it doesn't appear in the standard NTRU encryption algorithm, similar multiplications appear elsewhere) is that $p$ is an integer while $r$ is an NTRU ring element, and so this is actually scalar multiplication (where each coefficient in the polynomial that makes up $r$ is multiplied by the integer $p$).
This distinction, however, is really given by the types of the operands, and not how the multiplication operation is expressed.
